# How to use componentWillUnmount to remove setInterval in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, setinterval, react-component

I have two Intervals that is running in main Home Page when I move to other pages I get memory leak error and I Know that I should use componentWillUnmount so that the Interval stops running in other pages but I don't know how to achieve this. can somebody please help.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.widthSlider();
    this.startAnimate();
    const wow = new WOW();
    wow.init();
  }
  startAnimate = () => {
    const arr = [
      "One",
      "Two",
      "Three",
      "Four",
      "Five",
      "Six",
      "Seven",
      "Eight",
      "Nine"
    ];
    let counter = 1;
    setInterval(() => {
      if (counter === 9) {
        counter = 0;
        this.setState(defaultState());
      } else {
        const state = this.state;
        state[
          `animateLeft${arr[counter]}`
        ] = `animated fadeInLeftBig delay-${arr[counter].toLowerCase()}`;
        state[
          `animateRight${arr[counter]}`
        ] = `animated fadeInRightBig delay-${arr[counter].toLowerCase()}`;
        this.setState(state);
      }
      counter++;
    }, 7000);
  };

  widthSlider = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      const slide = this.state.width + 100;
      this.state.width === 800
        ? this.setState({
            width: 0
          })
        : this.setState({
            width: slide
          });
    }, 7000);
  };
  componentWillUnmount(){
    //clear Interval here
  }
```

Comment: Save the interval somewhere so you can clear it. `this.interval_id = setInterval(() => ... )` and `clearInterval( this.inetrval_id )`. Either somewhere in state or somewhere in a private variable. ( Whatever the React preference is )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically, what you need is to use the [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) function in your `componentWillUnmount`.

in order to use it, you need to save your interval ID, it is mostly done on the `componentDidMount()` or in the `constructor()`

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    // references to 
    this.sliderInterval = null;
    this.animateInterval = null;

 }

 componentDidMount() {

    this.widthSlider();
    this.startAnimate();
    const wow = new WOW();
    wow.init();
  }

  startAnimate = () => {
    const arr = [
      "One",
      "Two",
      "Three",
      "Four",
      "Five",
      "Six",
      "Seven",
      "Eight",
      "Nine"
    ];
    let counter = 1;
    //save the interval Id
    this.animateInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (counter === 9) {
        counter = 0;
        this.setState(defaultState());
      } else {
        const state = this.state;
        state[
          `animateLeft${arr[counter]}`
        ] = `animated fadeInLeftBig delay-${arr[counter].toLowerCase()}`;
        state[
          `animateRight${arr[counter]}`
        ] = `animated fadeInRightBig delay-${arr[counter].toLowerCase()}`;
        this.setState(state);
      }
      counter++;
    }, 7000);
  };

  widthSlider = () => {
    //save the interval Id
    this.sliderInterval = setInterval(() => {
      const slide = this.state.width + 100;
      this.state.width === 800
        ? this.setState({
            width: 0
          })
        : this.setState({
            width: slide
          });
    }, 7000);
  };
  componentWillUnmount(){
      // clearing the intervals
      if(this.sliderInterval) clearInterval(this.sliderInterval)
      if(this.animateInterval) clearInterval(this.animateInterval)
  }
```

Comment: If you`ve websocket disconnected then reconnected your interval doesnt cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setState` to save the interval id returned from `setInterval` like so:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.widthSlider();
    this.startAnimate();
    const wow = new WOW();
    wow.init();
  }
  startAnimate = () => {
    const arr = [
      "One",
      "Two",
      "Three",
      "Four",
      "Five",
      "Six",
      "Seven",
      "Eight",
      "Nine"
    ];
    let counter = 1;
    let animateInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (counter === 9) {
        counter = 0;
        this.setState(defaultState());
      } else {
        const state = this.state;
        state[
          `animateLeft${arr[counter]}`
        ] = `animated fadeInLeftBig delay-${arr[counter].toLowerCase()}`;
        state[
          `animateRight${arr[counter]}`
        ] = `animated fadeInRightBig delay-${arr[counter].toLowerCase()}`;
        this.setState(state);
      }
      counter++;
    }, 7000);
    this.setState({ animateInterval: animateInterval});
  };

  widthSlider = () => {
    let sliderInterval = setInterval(() => {
      const slide = this.state.width + 100;
      this.state.width === 800
        ? this.setState({
            width: 0
          })
        : this.setState({
            width: slide
          });
    }, 7000);
    this.setState({ sliderInterval : sliderInterval });
  };
  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.state.sliderInterval);
    clearInterval(this.state.animateInterval);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the interval in some variable

example:

```
this.myinterval = setInterval(...) or this.setState({ myinterval : setInterval(...) })
```

to lately clear it in hook "componenWillMount":

```
clearInterval(this.myinterval) or clearInterval(this.state.myinterval)
```